# Rotating $y=9x-x^2$ along y axis

Tags: integration, solid-of-revolution

Say we have a surface D in xy plane limited by x axis and $y=9x-x^2$. I need to calculate volume formed by rotating D along x axis and y axis.

For x axis it's easy. The curve is limited by (0, 9). If I did the calculations correctly the volume should be:

$$V_x = \pi\int_{b}^{a}{(f(x))^2dx} = \pi\int_{0}^{9}{(9x-x^2)^2dx} = 19683/10*\pi$$

But how would we calculate the volume for y axis? I tried to do it like this. I inverted the function which gives me two functions:

$$y = \frac{9\pm\sqrt{81-4x}}{2}$$

Now I could calculate the volume using integral formed by summing up volumes along x axis.

Then I basically moved the curves down 9 units along y axis, to make it easier to calculate the volume. The new function is now:

$$y = \frac{\sqrt{81-4x}}{2}$$

Finally I calculated the volume with:

$$V = \pi\int_{0}^{20.25}{\frac{81-4x}{4}dx} = 6561/32*\pi$$

This gives me half of the volume. And the full volume is then $V_y = 6561/16*\pi$.

This doesn't seem to be the correct answer however.

Comment: Try looking at the method of cylindrical shells

Comment: @AnikPatel Thanks! But shouldn't just inverting the function and then rotating it along x axis work also?

Comment: You forgot about the $\pm$ of the square root. You need to integrate both and add the volumes since the principal square root is not the true inverse of $x^2$. I can write a full answer if you like

Comment: @AnikPatel Solved the problem easily with shell method, thank you! But I'm really curious about solving it the other way. Would appreciate if you could post it!

Comment: You can "invert" the function (more precisely, solving $y=f(x)$ since $f$ is not invertible) but, as you have seen, it leads to not so simple computations. There are also cases where computing an "inverse" is very hard or impossible (consider $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ for $0\le x\le \pi$ for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cylindrical shells, the integral is very straightforward and gives $\frac{2187\pi}{2}$. However, if you want to use the inversion method you need to consider one extra step. Firstly, solving $y=9x-x^2$ for $x$ via quadratic formula
$$x=\frac{1}{2}(9\pm\sqrt{81-4y})$$
Now we have 2 curves. The formula for finding the volume of revolution in between 2 curves is
$$\pi\int_a^b f(x)^2-g(x)^2dx$$
In our problem, the top curve is
$$x=\frac{1}{2}(9+\sqrt{81-4y})=f(x)$$
and the lower curve is
$$x=\frac{1}{2}(9-\sqrt{81-4y})=g(x)$$

The bounds of integration will be 0 and 20.25 as you calculated in your question. Plugging in $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ gives

$$\pi\int_0^{20.5} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}(9+\sqrt{81-4y}\bigg)^2 - \bigg(\frac{1}{2}(9-\sqrt{81-4y})\bigg)^2dy$$

The integral is simple enough to solve and gives the desired answer of $\frac{2187\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Use the cylinderical shell method,

$$V=\int 2\pi r h ~dr$$

Here $r$ is the horizontal distance between the point $P$ on your curve to the y-axis, hence $r=x$, and $h$ is the height of the point $P$, which is $h=y=9x-x^2$, plug in and note the integral limits are from $0$ to $9$,

$$V=\int_0^9 2\pi x (9x-x^2) ~dx$$

You can proceed from here.